# Global Accelerator issue when connected to Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, aws-global-accelerator

I have a Global accelerator connected to elastic beanstalk in 3 regions(US, AU, EU).

The issue is whenever I hit the global accelerator it responds with the certificate of the ALB thats connected to the elastic beanstalk which causes the browser to block the response saying incorrect common name.

Each ALB has its own seperate url eg: server-au.domain.com, server-eu.domain.com.

Global accelerator has its own custom domain name and ssl. How do we make sure that the certificate of global accelerator is passed instead of where the request is forwarded to?

All certificates are handled by AWS certificate manager and dns records by Route 53.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple certificates for the elastic beanstalk under load balancer of ec2 settings.